# Prove of function is surjective iff it has a right inverse using the well-ordering Theorem

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

As mentioned in the title I should prove that a function $f\colon X\to Y$ is surjective if and only if there exists a function $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g=id_Y$ using the well ordering Theorem (i.e. that every set can be well-ordered).

Of course the statement is well known and not so difficult to prove but I don't know how to use the well ordering Theorem for the proof.

Comment: As far as I know, the wel-ordering principle is a statement about the positive integers, are $X$ and $Y$ subsets of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: maybe you're referring to the well ordering **theorem** which states that every set can be well-ordered.

Comment: I'm curious, how would you prove it without using well-order? I find it much more natural to use it than to use some sort of choice.

Comment: In my assignment it is stated with the well ordering principle, but I agree after looking up the exact terminology that the well ordering Theorem which states that every set can be well-ordered must be the right name. But I still don't know how to prove the statment using that.

Comment: I think I got it on my own. I was never really careful which preimage to choose, with the well ordering principle it is easy to get it well defined.

Comment: Even though my comment was prompted from curiosity, I later realised that if you took it seriously, it could nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, when you choose a preimage for each point, you are using the axiom of choice. It’s easy to see why the well ordering principle implies the axiom of choice, cause it allows you to define your choices as the least.

Comment: ^ realize I made the mistake noted above of calling this the “well ordering principle” rather than the “well ordering theorem”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the well-ordering principle, $X$ can be well-ordered.

"$\Rightarrow$" For every $y\in Y$, consider $f^{-1}(y)\subset X$ which is a non-empty subset, because $f$ is surjective. Using the well-order it has a least element $x_y$. Now, define $g(y):=x_y$. Then $f(g(y))=f(x_y)=y$, so $f\circ g=id_Y$.

"$\Leftarrow$" $id_Y$ is surjective, so $f\circ g$ is surjective, so $f$ must be surjective. No need of the well ordering principle here.